# Trim String Extract Portion of Varying length String

Tags: excel

I have strings like this but of varying lengths:

|___PADDY555555 A BURGSTEEL (CORE)   Rev:    Alt:    Seq:

I want to extract the "PADDY555555 A" from each string in the column. The left side of the string is fixed, I only want character numbers 5 - 18 (from left to right) to be placed in the cell to the right of the string.

I was using this but it is not working for varying lengths:

=MID(A17,7,LEN(A17)-47)

Comment: Your formula doesn't match your description. What's the `7` for?

Comment: and why not just `=MID(A1,5,14)`

Comment: You should do this =MID(A1,5,13)

Comment: @YairI characters from the 5th to the 18th have 14 characters.

Comment: @Scott Craner he doesnt want the space after the "A", he wants this "PADDY555555 A" and not this "PADDY555555 A "

Comment: The OP stated `I only want character numbers 5 - 18`.  `18-5+1` = `14` or better yet count: `5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18`  there are 14 numbers.  I am going by what the OP stated. @YairI

Comment: @Scott Craner He also put a formula that starts on 7. you can see that he doesn't really understand. he gave an example and my comment do that exact task. your solution is also good so let him use what ever he wants.

Comment: Yes thank you I was able to find the solution in the comments above.